# Vectortile connection labels appear on top of everything else

Tags: qgis, labeling, vector-tiles, basemap, draw-order

I have a vectortile connection using a json style with symbology and labels. Even though the layer is set under my other layers, the labels appear on top of everything else:

[image]

I know that labels normally appear on top of all symbologies, which is sufficient for most cases. But when using a vectortile connection to display a basemap, I want the contents of my map above those labels. Is there a way to achieve this?